# How get total salary based on salary partition by day

Tags: sql-server

This is my input table

```
    Create table #table1(id int, fn varchar(20), startdate varchar(20), id1 varcahr, salary int)
    insert #table1
    select 1, 'Joe', '2019-01-01', 'A', 100
    union select 1, 'Joe', '2019-01-01', 'B',200
    union select 1, 'Joe', '2019-01-05', 'D',400
    union select 1, 'Joe', '2019-01-06', 'E',500
    union select 2, 'john', '2019-01-05', 'F',250
    union select 2, 'john', '2019-01-05', 'F',250
   union select 2, 'john', '2019-01-06', 'G',200
   union select 2, 'john', '2019-01-06', 'H',230
  union select 2, 'john', '2019-01-07', 'I',310
```

[image: input tabel]

But I require output like 
group by id, fn, start date, salary and get sum in new column total

[image: Bur]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the windowed version of `sum()`.

```
SELECT id,
       fn,
       startdate,
       id1,
       salary,
       sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY id,
                                      fn,
                                      startdate) total
       FROM #table1;
```

Comment: Thank you for quick responce